# How to write a stream to a file in Windows Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

There are lots of questions around, but mostly are about writing strings to a file. I'm a bit confused!

**What is the proper way to write a stream to a file?**

what I did:

```
Stream stream = await GetStream(source);

var file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("TempUsersFile", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(fileStream))
{
    // How can I write to buffer and write to the file
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of writing a stream to file and they also depend on your needs. The method below performs *asynchronous* operation with a specified buffer:

```
public async Task SaveStreamToFile(Stream streamToSave, string fileName, CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (Stream fileStram = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        int bytesread = 0;
        while ((bytesread = await streamToSave.ReadAsync(buf, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            await fileStram.WriteAsync(buf, 0, bytesread);
            cancelToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
}
```

I've implemented also a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in case there will be a need to cancel the long running Task.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the StreamReader and StreamWriter classes:

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outstream);
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(instream);

 while (!sr.EndOfStream)
 {
    int ch = sr.Read();
    sw.Write(ch);
 }
```